# Adding days to a datetime query

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

I am fairly new to Powershell- and the best way i find learning is by doing.  Basically, i was looking to get the password expiry dates for users by getting the 'pwdlastset' and adding 90 days to it (that's our GPO retention time).  I got this far - but couldnt get the two to play ball together:

`$90days = New-TimeSpan -days 90
$pwdlastset = @{n='pwdLastSet';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet) }}`

I tried to add the two datetime's together- but nothing happened.  Please can anyone provide the assist ?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: `$pwdlastset = $pwdlastset.AddDays(90)`, assuming your `$pwdlastset` is a `DateTime` object to begin with?

Comment: @gravity Nice - please post as answer so can be accepted and question marked answered.

Comment: Thanks for help. I still couldnt figure it out so i just used the `.adddays(90)` like you did in the example at the end- `$pwdlastset= @{n='LastChangedPwd'; E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdlastset)}}
Get-aduser -filter {name -like 'User*'} -properties * | select name, $pwdlastset, @{n='DONC'; E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdlastset).AddDays(90)}}` it gave me what i wanted in the end- thanks for the help again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object, `$pwdlastset`, is a `DateTime` object, you can simply use the `AddDays(#)` function, like so:

`$pwdlastset = $pwdlastset.AddDays(90)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is the AddDays function.  You can use it with a DateTime object like so

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
```

Negative numbers will be in the past (subtracting from the date).  When you do comparisons, remember that earlier dates are "less than" later dates (i.e. -lt or -gt date comparisons)